# How to call Errors-in-variables models function not working

Tags: r

I am trying to do a EIV regression but the function from the `eivtools` package is not working for some reason. When I try to call `eivreg()` I get a could not find function "eivreg" error message.

I am running R 4.3.0 and the package asks for 3.4 or higher

Is there another function that works similarly?

Thank you for your help

Example from their R documentation (I got the error when  I tried to call eivreg)

```
library(eivtools)
set.seed(1001)
## simulate data with covariates x1, x2 and z.
.n    <- 1000
.d    <- data.frame(x1 = rnorm(.n))
.d$x2 <- sqrt(0.5)*.d$x1 + rnorm(.n, sd=sqrt(0.5))
.d$z  <- as.numeric(.d$x1 + .d$x2 > 0)

## generate outcome
## true regression parameters are c(2,1,1,-1)
.d$y  <- 2.0 + 1.0*.d$x1 + 1.0*.d$x2 - 1.0*.d$z + rnorm(.n)

## generate error-prone covariates w1 and w2
Sigma_error <- diag(c(0.20, 0.30))
dimnames(Sigma_error) <- list(c("w1","w2"), c("w1","w2"))
.d$w1 <- .d$x1 + rnorm(.n, sd = sqrt(Sigma_error["w1","w1"]))
.d$w2 <- .d$x2 + rnorm(.n, sd = sqrt(Sigma_error["w2","w2"]))

## fit EIV regression specifying known measurement error covariance matrix
.mod1 <- eivreg(y ~ w1 + w2 + z, data = .d, Sigma_error = Sigma_error)
print(class(.mod1))
.tmp <- summary(.mod1)
print(class(.tmp))
print(.tmp)

## fit EIV regression specifying known reliabilities.  Note that
## point estimator is slightly different from .mod1 because
## the correction matrix S must be estimated when the reliability
## is known.
.lambda <- c(1,1) / (c(1,1) + diag(Sigma_error))
.mod2 <- eivreg(y ~ w1 + w2 + z, data = .d, reliability = .lambda)
print(summary(.mod2))
```

Comment: `eivreg` function in this package is exported so it should be available. It's not clear what's going on and would need a reproducible example to go further.

Comment: Hi, I tried their example to test it and I got the error message I will add their example

Answer (score 0):

I found that there was a problem with JAGS package so I had to update the package